# How to match a separate dome mesh for an eye to an irregular eye hole perimeter?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've got a simple head mesh with eye holes already cut and I would like to add eyes as a separate mesh. I would like to maintain the dome-like topology of the new eye mesh while matching the existing eye hole perimeter. This is a bit of a challenge since the eye holes are bit irregular in all axes (part of the design).

I've only got a few flight hours in blender, but so far I've tried simple deform, mesh deform and shrinkwrap modifiers to match the eye mesh to the eye perimeter. I've also tried making a grid fill of the eye perimeter and then proportional editing to grab and pull out but the shape turns out pretty bad. I also tried insetting and extruding the eye perimeter to stairstep new geometry in a dome-like fashion, but couldn't get the results to be dome-like.

If I can utilize modifiers to get me pretty close then I can tweak vertices from there.

Final utility: to be separate meshes for 3d printing ... therefore the number of vertices on the eyehole don't necessarily need to match the eye.

(Next time I will probably model the eyes before making the eye holes.)

[image: mesh image 1]

[image: mesh image 2]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can show your combination proportional edit .. shrink wrap effort.  Please consider curve modifier.

Comment: so what about duplicating the edge loop of the eye hole and beginning to extrude inwards, etc? Maybe share your file so that we can give a try? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: thanks @moonboots - just added

Comment: Thanks for the insight mates. I ended up rewinding the clock to an earlier, simpler mesh and added a couple of simple deform modifiers after a shrinkwrap to some freshly modeled eyes. This [curved surface video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrlfmcQ2lCs) helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shape is a bit hard to work as it is already high in polygons, you should not work with high-poly as long as you are not satisfied with the whole shape in my opinion (and even afterwards, keep it low-poly, use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth, and only apply it if necessary), but, starting with what you're sharing, what you could do is duplicate the outer edge loop, simplify it (header menu > *Select > Checker Deselect*, then <kbd>X</kbd> > Dissolve vertices):

[image]

Then extrude inwards and fill:

[image]

Put it on the head, make some adjustments:

[image]

If you want to smooth it, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier (3 subdivisions) and apply:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I like the checker deselect / dissolve trick. What are ur keystrokes for "extrude inwards and fill" ?

Comment: E to extrude, then scale, use the top view to move the extrusions a bit forwards, at the end, when you need to fill the hole, join the vertices with F, fill the faces with F as well...